# 'android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, annotations, androidx, non-nullable

[image: 'android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package]

I get this warning when I try to list data. 
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're referring to the Android platform's internal annotations, which aren't the ones you want to use for your own code.  For your code, you should import the AndroidX versions of those annotations:

[`androidx.annotation.NonNull`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/NonNull)

[`androidx.annotation.Nullable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Nullable)

etc. (note the extra `x` in `androidx` vs `android`)

You'll also want to make sure you have declared a dependency on `androidx.annotation:annotation` in your `build.gradle` (see [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation) for the latest version information)