# 'android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'.Cannot be accessed from outside package. Same also for 'Nullable'

Tags: android, annotations

I got these warnings:
**'android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'.Cannot be accessed from outside package**

**'android.annotation.Nullable' is not public in 'android.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package.**

I also got this warning:
**Cannot resolve symbol 'UnSupportedAppUsage'.**

I tried these two imports based on the advice on this thread ['android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387407/android-annotation-nonnull-is-not-public-in-android-annotation-cannot-be-ac) but they did not help.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

Here is my whole code from Handler.java -file (I tooks all the comments away):

```
package android.os;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.*;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Printer;

import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

 
public class Handler {
   
    private static final boolean FIND_POTENTIAL_LEAKS = false;
    private static final String TAG = "Handler";
    private static Handler MAIN_THREAD_HANDLER = null;

    
    public interface Callback {
        
        boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg);
    }
    
  
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
    }
    
    
    public void dispatchMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        if (msg.callback != null) {
            handleCallback(msg);
        } else {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                if (mCallback.handleMessage(msg)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }

   
    public Handler() {
        this(null, false);
    }

   
     
    public Handler(@Nullable Callback callback) {
        this(callback, false);
    }

    
    public Handler(@NonNull Looper looper) {
        this(looper, null, false);
    }

   
    public Handler(@NonNull Looper looper, @Nullable Callback callback) {
        this(looper, callback, false);
    }

  
   
    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    public Handler(boolean async) {
        this(null, async);
    }

  
    public Handler(@Nullable Callback callback, boolean async) {
        if (FIND_POTENTIAL_LEAKS) {
            final Class<? extends Handler> klass = getClass();
            if ((klass.isAnonymousClass() || klass.isMemberClass() || klass.isLocalClass()) &&
                    (klass.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) == 0) {
                Log.w(TAG, "The following Handler class should be static or leaks might occur: " +
                    klass.getCanonicalName());
            }
        }

        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        if (mLooper == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Can't create handler inside thread " + Thread.currentThread()
                        + " that has not called Looper.prepare()");
        }
        mQueue = mLooper.mQueue;
        mCallback = callback;
        mAsynchronous = async;
    }


    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    public Handler(@NonNull Looper looper, @Nullable Callback callback, boolean async) {
        mLooper = looper;
        mQueue = looper.mQueue;
        mCallback = callback;
        mAsynchronous = async;
    }

   
    @NonNull
    public static Handler createAsync(@NonNull Looper looper) {
        if (looper == null) throw new NullPointerException("looper must not be null");
        return new Handler(looper, null, true);
    }

   
   
    @NonNull
    public static Handler createAsync(@NonNull Looper looper, @NonNull Callback callback) {
        if (looper == null) throw new NullPointerException("looper must not be null");
        if (callback == null) throw new NullPointerException("callback must not be null");
        return new Handler(looper, callback, true);
    }

    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    @NonNull
    public static Handler getMain() {
        if (MAIN_THREAD_HANDLER == null) {
            MAIN_THREAD_HANDLER = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
        return MAIN_THREAD_HANDLER;
    }

    
    @NonNull
    public static Handler mainIfNull(@Nullable Handler handler) {
        return handler == null ? getMain() : handler;
    }

  
    @NonNull
    public String getTraceName(@NonNull Message message) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(getClass().getName()).append(": ");
        if (message.callback != null) {
            sb.append(message.callback.getClass().getName());
        } else {
            sb.append("#").append(message.what);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

   
    @NonNull
    public String getMessageName(@NonNull Message message) {
        if (message.callback != null) {
            return message.callback.getClass().getName();
        }
        return "0x" + Integer.toHexString(message.what);
    }

   
    @NonNull
    public final Message obtainMessage()
    {
        return Message.obtain(this);
    }


    @NonNull
    public final Message obtainMessage(int what)
    {
        return Message.obtain(this, what);
    }
    
    
    @NonNull
    public final Message obtainMessage(int what, @Nullable Object obj) {
        return Message.obtain(this, what, obj);
    }

   
    @NonNull
    public final Message obtainMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        return Message.obtain(this, what, arg1, arg2);
    }
    
 
    @NonNull
    public final Message obtainMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2, @Nullable Object obj) {
        return Message.obtain(this, what, arg1, arg2, obj);
    }


    public final boolean post(@NonNull Runnable r) {
       return  sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), 0);
    }
   
    public final boolean postAtTime(@NonNull Runnable r, long uptimeMillis) {
        return sendMessageAtTime(getPostMessage(r), uptimeMillis);
    }
    
    public final boolean postAtTime(
            @NonNull Runnable r, @Nullable Object token, long uptimeMillis) {
        return sendMessageAtTime(getPostMessage(r, token), uptimeMillis);
    }
    
   
 
    public final boolean postDelayed(@NonNull Runnable r, long delayMillis) {
        return sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r), delayMillis);
    }
    
    public final boolean postDelayed(Runnable r, int what, long delayMillis) {
        return sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r).setWhat(what), delayMillis);
    }

  
 
    public final boolean postDelayed(
            @NonNull Runnable r, @Nullable Object token, long delayMillis) {
        return sendMessageDelayed(getPostMessage(r, token), delayMillis);
    }
   
    public final boolean postAtFrontOfQueue(@NonNull Runnable r) {
        return sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(getPostMessage(r));
    }

   
    public final boolean runWithScissors(@NonNull Runnable r, long timeout) {
        if (r == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("runnable must not be null");
        }
        if (timeout < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout must be non-negative");
        }

        if (Looper.myLooper() == mLooper) {
            r.run();
            return true;
        }

        BlockingRunnable br = new BlockingRunnable(r);
        return br.postAndWait(this, timeout);
    }

  
    public final void removeCallbacks(@NonNull Runnable r) {
        mQueue.removeMessages(this, r, null);
    }

  
    public final void removeCallbacks(@NonNull Runnable r, @Nullable Object token) {
        mQueue.removeMessages(this, r, token);
    }

 
    public final boolean sendMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        return sendMessageDelayed(msg, 0);
    }

  
    public final boolean sendEmptyMessage(int what)
    {
        return sendEmptyMessageDelayed(what, 0);
    }

  
    public final boolean sendEmptyMessageDelayed(int what, long delayMillis) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = what;
        return sendMessageDelayed(msg, delayMillis);
    }



    public final boolean sendEmptyMessageAtTime(int what, long uptimeMillis) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = what;
        return sendMessageAtTime(msg, uptimeMillis);
    }

 
   
    public final boolean sendMessageDelayed(@NonNull Message msg, long delayMillis) {
        if (delayMillis < 0) {
            delayMillis = 0;
        }
        return sendMessageAtTime(msg, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delayMillis);
    }
    
    public boolean sendMessageAtTime(@NonNull Message msg, long uptimeMillis) {
        MessageQueue queue = mQueue;
        if (queue == null) {
            RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException(
                    this + " sendMessageAtTime() called with no mQueue");
            Log.w("Looper", e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
        return enqueueMessage(queue, msg, uptimeMillis);
    }

 
    public final boolean sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(@NonNull Message msg) {
        MessageQueue queue = mQueue;
        if (queue == null) {
            RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException(
                this + " sendMessageAtTime() called with no mQueue");
            Log.w("Looper", e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
        return enqueueMessage(queue, msg, 0);
    }

   
   
    public final boolean executeOrSendMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        if (mLooper == Looper.myLooper()) {
            dispatchMessage(msg);
            return true;
        }
        return sendMessage(msg);
    }

    private boolean enqueueMessage(@NonNull MessageQueue queue, @NonNull Message msg,
            long uptimeMillis) {
        msg.target = this;
        msg.workSourceUid = ThreadLocalWorkSource.getUid();

        if (mAsynchronous) {
            msg.setAsynchronous(true);
        }
        return queue.enqueueMessage(msg, uptimeMillis);
    }

  
    public final void removeMessages(int what) {
        mQueue.removeMessages(this, what, null);
    }

    public final void removeMessages(int what, @Nullable Object object) {
        mQueue.removeMessages(this, what, object);
    }

    
    public final void removeCallbacksAndMessages(@Nullable Object token) {
        mQueue.removeCallbacksAndMessages(this, token);
    }

  
    public final boolean hasMessages(int what) {
        return mQueue.hasMessages(this, what, null);
    }

   
    public final boolean hasMessagesOrCallbacks() {
        return mQueue.hasMessages(this);
    }

    
    public final boolean hasMessages(int what, @Nullable Object object) {
        return mQueue.hasMessages(this, what, object);
    }

  
    public final boolean hasCallbacks(@NonNull Runnable r) {
        return mQueue.hasMessages(this, r, null);
    }

 
    @NonNull
    public final Looper getLooper() {
        return mLooper;
    }

    public final void dump(@NonNull Printer pw, @NonNull String prefix) {
        pw.println(prefix + this + " @ " + SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
        if (mLooper == null) {
            pw.println(prefix + "looper uninitialized");
        } else {
            mLooper.dump(pw, prefix + "  ");
        }
    }

   
    public final void dumpMine(@NonNull Printer pw, @NonNull String prefix) {
        pw.println(prefix + this + " @ " + SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
        if (mLooper == null) {
            pw.println(prefix + "looper uninitialized");
        } else {
            mLooper.dump(pw, prefix + "  ", this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Handler (" + getClass().getName() + ") {"
        + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
        + "}";
    }

    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    final IMessenger getIMessenger() {
        synchronized (mQueue) {
            if (mMessenger != null) {
                return mMessenger;
            }
            mMessenger = new MessengerImpl();
            return mMessenger;
        }
    }

    private final class MessengerImpl extends IMessenger.Stub {
        public void send(Message msg) {
            msg.sendingUid = Binder.getCallingUid();
            Handler.this.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    private static Message getPostMessage(Runnable r) {
        Message m = Message.obtain();
        m.callback = r;
        return m;
    }

    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    private static Message getPostMessage(Runnable r, Object token) {
        Message m = Message.obtain();
        m.obj = token;
        m.callback = r;
        return m;
    }

    private static void handleCallback(Message message) {
        message.callback.run();
    }

    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    final Looper mLooper;
    final MessageQueue mQueue;
    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    final Callback mCallback;
    final boolean mAsynchronous;
    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    IMessenger mMessenger;

    private static final class BlockingRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final Runnable mTask;
        private boolean mDone;

        public BlockingRunnable(Runnable task) {
            mTask = task;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mTask.run();
            } finally {
                synchronized (this) {
                    mDone = true;
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean postAndWait(Handler handler, long timeout) {
            if (!handler.post(this)) {
                return false;
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                if (timeout > 0) {
                    final long expirationTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + timeout;
                    while (!mDone) {
                        long delay = expirationTime - SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                        if (delay <= 0) {
                            return false; // timeout
                        }
                        try {
                            wait(delay);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    while (!mDone) {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot really compile platform sources with an app sdk.

Comment: @laalto. How then? Sorry, I am very beginner with Android Studio.

Comment: Why do you need to compile `android.os.Handler` platform code? What's the problem you're solving in the first place?

Comment: Every time i run this app, it gives the following error messages and says: that unfortunately app has stopped. For example `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.esimerkki.doodl2.DoodleView com.esimerkki.doodl2.FirstFragment.getDoodleView()' on a null object reference          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
`

Comment: That's a different problem. There's Handler in the call stack yes and you might click yourself into its source code (that shows red since platform building blocks are missing) but the problem is not there. It's your code trying to invoke `getDoodleView()` method on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added **androidx** library to your app level gradle file dependencies section?

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

If yes, please explain the error that you are getting with **androidx.annotation.NonNull** package. Because the errors that you have provided in your question are for **'android.annotation.Nullable'**

Comment: Yes @Don Peter.  `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`

Comment: Ok. then could you explain the exact error you are getting when using @NonNull androidx.annotations?